# Vault of Glass loot chests

Tags: destiny

If I do Vault Of Glass on easy and obtain all loot chests then repeat on hard, will those loot chests "
reset"????

Side note: anyone know the chance of getting exotic stuff from the raid, because I swear I have a curse on my character (have had to buy every legendary and exotic item - level 29)

Thanks guys and sorry if this question has been addressed already :)

Comment: yes the chests will reset on hard and it's nearly impossible to get exotics on normal (only those exotics which can dop everywhere can drop in normal, the raid exotics just drop on hard)

Comment: This looks like a dupe of the question mentioned above.  The only issue that the other answer doesn't cover is which drops from the raid can be exotics.  I would suggest the questioner ask that question independently.

Comment: The left Gorgon chest and Aetheon can drop exotics.  The chances are pretty minimal.  Obviously there is no stated percentage but I would estimate that there is something like a < 5% chance of an exotic dropping in the raid.